# Coppee Pastee Fatal error when trying to install fieldtype

Tags: ee2, fieldtype, update

I receive this error when trying to install Coppee Pastee in ExpressionEngine 2.8.0

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Fieldtype::EE_Fieldtype() in /System/expressionengine/third_party/copee_pastee/ft.copee_pastee.php on line 23

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace "parent::EE_Fieldtype();" on line 23 of ft.copee_pastee.php with "parent::__construct();"